# Remove user from G Suite

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-workspace-for-business

I'm trying to remove a user account from my Google Admin Console.

However it won't let me unless I specify an account to transfer all the data to:

[image]

As you can see, the 'Delete user' button is ghosted. The only way the button becomes active is if I enter an email address in the 'Transfer' field to transfer all the data too.

Thing is, I don't want to transfer over any data from the account, I just want to delete it.

Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the box next to Brand Accounts (and other checked transfer items...uncheck all the boxes to transfer nothing) and the delete button should become available.